# Problem with UpdateResource (Out of memory)

Tags: delphi, resources, out-of-memory

I use this code to attach a file as a resource to an executable file :

```
interface
type
  TBuffer = Array [0 .. 0] of Byte;
  PBuffer = ^TBuffer;

Procedure AttachFile();
var
  DataLength: DWord;
  Data: PBuffer;
begin
  FS := TFileStream.Create(Filename, fmOpenRead);
  try
    FS.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
    DataLength := FS.Size;
    GetMem(Data, DataLength);
    FS.Read(Data^, DataLength);
  finally
      FS.Free;
  end;
  UpdateResource(ResourceHandle, RT_RCDATA, pchar('ResName'),
    0, Data, DataLength);
  EndUpdateResource(ResourceHandle, false);
end;
```

The problem is that when i want to attach a `Larg` (1GB for example) file using this code, I'll receive this error : `Out of memory`.

*I also tried to split my file to smaller parts(for example : 100MB) and attach it using a `for ring` but it still doesn't work and i receive `Out of memory`*

Comment: Hi, It would certainly help having code that displays the problem.
I can see that you declare two variables that you're not using at all and not declaring some you are instead using. May you please rework it so that it "flows" and we can actually see what you're doing? Thank you! Andrea

Comment: You are attaching a resource of 1 gb ¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡ why? are you sure which uses a resource to store this larger file is the right approach?

Comment: I also tried to split my file to smaller parts(for example : 100MB) and attach it using a `for ring` but it still doesn't work and i receive Out of memory

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like some sort of malware to me. May I ask why you would need to attach a 1GB file as a resource? (Since you're going to be very unlikely to allocate a 1GB memory buffer with a call to GetMem with anything else running on your machine, even with 4GB RAM, it's highly unlikely you'd be able to access a 1GB resource on another machine that was running your app. That leads me to believe that your 'resource' is something you're trying to sneak onto the other machine without being noticed, which in turn makes me think you're up to no good...)

Answer (score 2):

Embedded resources aren't meant to be this big and you are apparently hitting the limits.

You should deliver this file as a standalone file alongside your executable.

Comment: Please help me to fix the problem. As i said i split the huge file to smaller parts but still receive `Out of memory` . so the problem is something else. would you check my code and help me to fix it?

Comment: the solution is not to use a resource for such a huge file

Comment: Clearly you are set on using a resource. I wouldn't recommend that but it's obviously your choice.

Comment: I have to use a resource and there is no choices for me.

Comment: @Kermia: Because **you're out of memory**. What part of that isn't clear?